# awk improve command - Count & Sum

Tags: awk

Would like to get your suggestion to improve this command and want to remove unwanted execution to avoid time consumption,
actually i am trying to find `CountOfLines and SumOf$6 group by $2,substr($3,4,6),substr($4,4,6),$10,$8,$6`.

GunZip Input file contains around 300 Mn rows of lines.

Input.gz

```
2067,0,09-MAY-12.04:05:14,09-MAY-12.04:05:14,21-MAR-16,600,INR,RO312,20120321_1C,K1,,32
2160,0,26-MAY-14.02:05:27,26-MAY-14.02:05:27,18-APR-18,600,INR,RO414,20140418_7,K1,,30
2160,0,26-MAY-14.02:05:27,26-MAY-14.02:05:27,18-APR-18,600,INR,RO414,20140418_7,K1,,30
2160,0,26-MAY-14.02:05:27,26-MAY-14.02:05:27,18-APR-18,600,INR,RO414,20140418_7,K1,,30
2104,5,13-JAN-13.01:01:38,,13-JAN-17,4150,INR,RO113,CD1301_RC50_B1_20130113,K2,,21
```

Am using the below command and working fine.

```
   zcat Input.gz | awk -F"," '{OFS=","; print $2,substr($3,4,6),substr($4,4,6),$10,$8,$6}'  | \
awk -F"," 'BEGIN {count=0; sum=0; OFS=","} {key=$0; a[key]++;b[key]=b[key]+$6} \
END {for (i in a) print i,a[i],b[i]}' >Output.txt
```

Output.txt

```
0,MAY-14,MAY-14,K1,RO414,600,3,1800
0,MAY-12,MAY-12,K1,RO312,600,1,600
5,JAN-13,,K2,RO113,4150,1,4150
```

Any suggestion to improve the above command are welcome ..

Comment: `b[key]=b[key]+$6` can be shortened to `b[key]+=$6` for a small efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more efficient:

```
zcat Input.gz | awk -F, '{key=$2","substr($3,4,6)","substr($4,4,6)","$10","$8","$6;++a[key];b[key]=b[key]+$6}END{for(i in a)print i","a[i]","b[i]}'
```

Output:

```
0,MAY-14,MAY-14,K1,RO414,600,3,1800
0,MAY-12,MAY-12,K1,RO312,600,1,600
5,JAN-13,,K2,RO113,4150,1,4150
```

Uncondensed form:

```
zcat Input.gz | awk -F, '{
    key = $2 "," substr($3, 4, 6) "," substr($4, 4, 6) "," $10 "," $8 "," $6
    ++a[key]
    b[key] = b[key] + $6
}
END {
    for (i in a)
        print i "," a[i] "," b[i]
}'
```

Comment: konsolebox, would like to understand how your's commamnd is print $2,substr($3, 4, 6) "," substr($4, 4, 6) "," $10 "," $8 "," $6
though you are not used print explicitly ...

Comment: @AVN I'm not sure if I follow but `$2 "," substr($3, 4, 6) "," substr($4, 4, 6) "," $10 "," $8 "," $6` is saved in `a[]` and is later printed in END with `i`. Nothing is printed until it. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one awk invocation by redefining the fields according to the first awk script, i.e. something like this:

```awk
$1 = $2
$2 = substr($3, 4, 6)
$3 = substr($4, 4, 6)
$4 = $10
$5 = $8
```

No need to change `$6` as that is the same field. Now if you base the key on the new fields, the second script will work almost unaltered. Here is how I would write it, moving the code into a script file for better readability and maintainability:

```
zcat Input.gz | awk -f parse.awk
```

Where `parse.awk` contains:

```awk
BEGIN {
  FS = OFS = ","
}

{ 
  $1 = $2
  $2 = substr($3, 4, 6)
  $3 = substr($4, 4, 6)
  $4 = $10
  $5 = $8

  key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4 OFS $5 OFS $6
  a[key]++
  b[key] += $6
}

END {
  for (i in a) 
    print i, a[i], b[i]
}
```

You can of course still run it as a one-liner, but it will look more cryptic:

```
zcat Input.gz | awk '{ key = $2 FS substr($3,4,6) FS substr($4,4,6) FS $10 FS $8 FS $6; a[key]++; b[key]+=$6 } END { for (i in a) print i,a[i],b[i] }' FS=, OFS=,
```

Output in both cases:

```
0,MAY-14,MAY-14,K1,RO414,600,3,1800
0,MAY-12,MAY-12,K1,RO312,600,1,600
5,JAN-13,,K2,RO113,4150,1,4150
```